# How to create a library with visual elements for drag&drop to another scene/window?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using c# for programming .net applications. I can use menus, tabs etc with ease.

Now, I need to create a library window that will contain various elements. The user will be able to drag-drop these elements to another window (scene). Moreover the user will be able to connect these elemet. A similar program window is shown below. I just cannot figure out how I can incorporate/create such a visual designer in my .net application. Which library or component can be used to create a visual designer like this?

Thanks a lot.

[Please click here for a sample GUI with visual designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA3lR.png)

Comment: I think you should ask this in https://stackoverflow.com/, in brief: each visual element in your sample is custom control (ex: panel holds : picturebox + label ) and drag drop feature done through events, each control has builtin events that need to be handled through what's called event_handler.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for WPF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/diagram) supports creating any kind of diagram with nodes and connectors. Palette support is built in and users can drag and drop symbols on to the canvas. It is a library that can be integrated into any desktop .NET application.

[image: Syncfusion Diagram Builder with Palette]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.